# Linked List C Insert function

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I have exam tomorrow in data structures and I want to figure out Insert function in this code. Please can you explain to me in function `Insert` why `temp->next = head`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node {

    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};

struct Node* head;

void Insert(int x) {

    struct Node *temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp->data = x;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if(head != NULL) { temp->next = head;}
    head = temp;


}

void Print() {

    struct Node* temp = head;
    printf("List is: ");

    while(temp != NULL) {

        printf(" %d",temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;

    }
    printf("\n");

}


int main() {

     head = NULL;

     Insert(1);
     Insert(2);
     Insert(3);
     Insert(4);
     Insert(5);

     Print();



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The old `head` becomes `temp->next`, `temp` becomes the new `head` pointer.

Comment: For simplicity, and unless it's an ordered list, you should always insert at the head; that's what it does.

Comment: but why program is not working when we delete this part ? is it keeping address of old head to print list ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comment -

> "but why program is not working when we delete this part ? is it
>   keeping address of old head to print list ?

No, it's not. Because here...

```
if(head != NULL) { temp->next = head;}
head = temp;
```

... we see if we remove `head = temp;` you will orphan your list because if `head == NULL` it will still be `NULL`. And if not, you have no link to `temp`, so you orphan `temp` and all other `insert`s.

The `if(head != NULL) { temp->next = head;}` statement ensures, if you *do* have one, your list is appended to the new `head` but without the `head = temp;` statement it wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

```
void Insert(int x) {

    struct Node *temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp->data = x;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if(head != NULL) { temp->next = head;}
    head = temp;


}
```

Let's see with example:-

```
insert(1);
```

would create new node and set it's data field to 1. then it checks if head is NULL. yes as this is first element we are inserting. So it makes head point to this element. That mean after this

```
head -> 1
```

Now you do

```
insert(2);
```

On the same line it would create node to accomodate 2. Next it checks if head is NULL. It's not so execute

```
temp->next = head;
```

means temp node's ( which is 2 ) next would be pointed to head (which is 1 right now ). After this statement

```
2 -> 1 (head)
```

And then you execute

```
head = temp;
```

which would make head point to 2 ( newly created node )

```
(head) 2->1
```

In this way you would continue adding element and keeping head pointer point to latest element added to your list. This would help you to later traverse the list using head pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You insert new nodes at the front of the list by replacing the head. The new head will be the newly allocated node `temp` and the old head will be the second node in the list, hence `temp->next`.

Such concepts can be easily thought out with the help on pencil and paper. Or with ASCII sketches, where `->` means a link via the `next` pointer and `|` means a direct pointer to a node which isn't a node link:

```
head
 | 
 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> NULL
```

Afer inserting 4, but before assigning the new head:

```
temp head
 |    |
 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> NULL
```

After assigning the new head:

```
head 
 |   
 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> NULL
```

Now you have a proper list where you can access all added nodes via the `head` and the `next` pointers. If you hadn't ressigned the `head`, you could only access the old nodes.

That also works for an empty list where `head == NULL`, except you can't access `head->next`.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs after you add new element in your linkedlist. when you add new element you have to make new element the head, so you have to point to previous head as the next item in the linked list.